# How to suppress job status output

Tags: powershell

I am trying to suppress this output

```
Id     Name            PSJobTypeName   State         HasMoreData     Location             Command
--     ----            -------------   -----         -----------     --------             -------
1      Job1            BackgroundJob   Running       True            localhost            ...
3      Job3            BackgroundJob   Running       True            localhost            ...
5      Job5            BackgroundJob   Running       True            localhost            ...
```

My code is written as following

```
foreach($line in $db) {
    $job = { 
            #code
            }
    $running = @(Get-Job | Where-Object { $_.State -eq 'Running' })
    if ($running.Count -le $jobLimit) {
        Start-Job -ScriptBlock $job 
    } else {
         $running | Wait-Job -Any | Out-Null
    }
    Get-Job | Receive-Job | Out-Null
}
```

I can not figure out what I am missing to hide this status output...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Also add `| Out-Null` to this line: `Start-Job -ScriptBlock $job`.

```bsh
foreach($line in $db) {
    $job = { 
            #code
            }
    $running = @(Get-Job | Where-Object { $_.State -eq 'Running' })
    if ($running.Count -le $jobLimit) {
        Start-Job -ScriptBlock $job | Out-Null
    } else {
         $running | Wait-Job -Any | Out-Null
    }
    Get-Job | Receive-Job | Out-Null
}
```